# PayPal Express Chekout no pay by credit/debit card option

Tags: paypal

I have a website which is using PayPal Express Checkout as a payment method.

It was working for 2 years without a problem but yesterday I noticed that the payment options are changed before there were 2 payment option presented to the user

1. Login and pay with PayPal account.
2. Do not have PayPal account pay by credit/debit card.

But now the second option is replaced by Create a PayPal account. There is no option to pay without having a PayPal account.

I have not changed anything.

Anybody knows why the Pay by credit/debit card is gone.

[image: before]

[image: now]

Comment: Hey Vladimir, have you had any luck? I currently have the same issue and am speaking to PayPal support. Unfortunately I'm yet to talk to anyone who knows anything, but will provide an update if I get it.

Comment: Has PayPal's support answered your question?!

Comment: are you using woocommerce?

Answer (score 2):

First make sure in your Paypal/Sandbox account the  PayPal Account have 
Optional: ON 
Go to -->
PayPal account's Profile -> More Options -> My Selling Tools -> Website Preferences screen.

And then set SolutionTypeType to Sole while making request for setExpressCheckout this will enable the option to Pay with your debit or credit card.
And you are done :)

Comment: I am trying for over 2 hours to accomplish "Pay by credit/debit card" without creating a PayPal account... but with no luck! I have tried your suggestions without resolving my problem! The thing is (... and it is very hard for me to believe it) that it works when I use the Opera browser and doesn't work with all the others (Firefox, IE 10, Google Chrome, Safari). Is that possible !?!?

Comment: Sorry for late.This is weird :(  but please try cleaning your browsers history, cookies may be that can help.Good luck

Answer (score 0):

What I know is earlier when you pay with credit card on paypal using express check out API it also create an account for that user and let user process different things like link bank account with paypal or credit card payment.

It is default behavior of paypal express checkout according to their new View

Answer (score -1):

PayPal displays different options for Express Checkout depending upon the COUNTRY selected (it will detect your IP address and set the country if no country is passed to the page).  eg Indonesia (etc) forces you to create a Paypal account whereas USA (etc) does not (and provides other options).

Comment: This doesn't appear to be true.  We tried the same account from US and elsewhere and the same problem exists.  Besides, when creating the test account in the Sandbox, it says the country in the address is the USA.  I assume it will take a users billing country rather than check by IP address.