# Paypal getting option payment through credit card(PHP)

Tags: php, paypal

Hi i am getting two options while integrating the paypal with my PHP code

**1. Pay via paypal
2. Create a paypal account**

Whereas i Need an option Of

**Payment through Debit/Credit Card**

How can i get that,,

i reffer to this[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362279/paypal-express-chekout-no-pay-by-credit-debit-card-option)  But unable to find the paypal profile and more options option, Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

The only way to force Guest Checkout (which is what PayPal calls it when somebody uses a credit card from their checkout pages without signing in to a PayPal account) is to use the [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/?mark=express%20checkout).

This will allow you to set parameters that provide the Guest Checkout experience in all instances where it's available.  Keep in mind that even with this configured correctly, Guest Checkout is simply not available for all buyers in all countries, so you still won't get it for 100% of your customers if you're selling world wide.

Guest Checkout is available in PayPal Standard Payments, too, but it's cookie based, so it's very unreliable.  If the browser in use has ever had anybody sign in to a PayPal account then it will assume the current user will be signing in, too, and it will not prominently display the Guest Checkout option.  This is what you are able to avoid by using the Express Checkout APIs.

This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the Express Checkout calls very quick and easy for you.  Specifically, you'll be working with:

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

In your SetExpressCheckout request you'll make sure to include the follow parameters:

- SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- LANDINGPAGE=Billing
- USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

This will ensure that the user sees the Guest Checkout experience.

Answer (score -1):

Direct processing of Credit Cards is deprecated.
But people can pay without PayPal account - it's called guest payments.

Use the PayPal API and allow [the optimal checkout](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/account-optional) to YES and then customers can pay either through credit card / paypal account.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/guest-payments/#